# Is it possible to redirect links to Pages instead of Projects in the Wordpress Power Builder plug-in?

Tags: html, wordpress, plugins

https://ld-wp.template-help.com/wordpress_62222_default/home-modern/?ld&top_panel_visibility=1

Below the landing page, links to Projects are organised in a grid using the Power Builder plugin, is there anyway to redirect these to Pages instead of Projects?

Alternatively is there a plug-in which performs a similar function for Pages?

Comment: Include what you have tried so far

Comment: Hi David, alternatively is there another plugin which does something similar for Pages?

Comment: when I inspect the element I can find the HTML to change the links, but I can't find it in php, is there a way of locating it?

Answer (score 0):

This plug-in allows you to change where links go: https://wordpress.org/plugins/page-links-to/

:^]